# Touchpad Settings not being saved

Tags: touchpad

I recently installed ubuntu on an HP 15-g039ca laptop and have been having nothing but headaches with the touchpad.

The default sensitivity is so high that just lightly brushing it causes it to register a tap and jump my cursor to wherever the mouse happens to be.

At first I was using xinput to manually change my sensitivity settings but they were not being saved.

Next i downloaded the gsynaptic manager since for some reason my system menu is missing several icons.

Now I am only able to make changes to my touchpad if I run sudo gpointing-device-settings from the terminal but again the settings are not being retained.

It is at the point that even the screen saver coming on causes the touchpad to revert to default settings

I did try disabling the touchpad all together however it has the same issue of defaulting as soon as the laptop kicks on the screensaver, goes to sleep, change user accounts, reboot, shutdown, etc...

I can't do any work on this laptop at this point so I'm also open to any suggestions for any other version of linux that doesn't have these issues.

running Xubuntu (14.04)

Comment: Still up for help or did you throw your box in the river ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the following file (tested on 16.04 4/14/2016):

```
sudo vi /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf
```

Adjust the 'touchpad' section to add Option "tapping" "True" and Option "DisableWhileTyping" "True" if you prefer this behavior.

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
    Option "Tapping" "True"
    Option "DisableWhileTyping" "True"
EndSection
```

Refer [This question describes it][1]

Other workaround can be to add the setting command in your .profile.